# When Imageflow does remove cached images

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, image-resizing, imageresizer, imageflow

I use the [`Imageflow`](https://github.com/imazen/imageflow-dotnet-server) package for resizing image in `asp.net core`.

it cache the images in `imageflow_cache` folder. But I don't know when cached images are deleted?

This is my configuration:

```
builder
    .Services
    .AddImageflowHybridCache(new HybridCacheOptions(Path.Combine(builder.Environment.WebRootPath, 
                                                                 "imageflow_cache"))
{
    CacheSizeLimitInBytes = (long)1 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 //1 GiB
});
```

When cached images are delete in `imageflow_cache` folder?

Can I set a time for deleting cached images?

Comment: Do you have any concerns about this issue?

Comment: @JasonPan No, I want to know when images are deleted. your answer was very helpful. (for DiskCache not Hybrid)

Comment: Hi Farhad, I found this link [DiskCache and Tiny Cache have been replaced by HybridCache](https://github.com/imazen/resizer/blob/develop/CHANGES.md#diskcache-and-tiny-cache-have-been-replaced-by-hybridcache).

Comment: The two packages seem have some relationship, I didn't confuse them.

Answer (score 2):

I read the source code and found [`CleanupStrategy`](https://github.com/imazen/imageflow-dotnet-server/blob/71865b556c810a4d8436a2a1f3c2d9b9453ce2af/src/Imazen.DiskCache/readme.md#cleanupstrategy).

I haven't the resources like you,So I according the source code and write code snipt below, you can refer it, if some properties not found, try to F12 and find it or share with us. Hope the code useful to you.

```
builder.Services.AddImageflowHybridCache(new HybridCacheOptions(Path.Combine(builder.Environment.WebRootPath, "imageflow_cache"))
{
    CacheSizeLimitInBytes = (long)1 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024, //1 GiB
    AutoClean = true,
    CleanupStrategy = "d.01:00:00" // delete files older than 1 day
});
```